# Hide Field and field name in infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I created a form in infopath. I'd like to show a section (multiple fields) only when the field name is checked. I was only able to hide the input part, but not the name. Is there a way to hide the fields and their name? When main field is checked the whole section show, otherwise hide/ collapse. The image below shows when field4 is not checked. The input for field1 doesn't show, but the name, field1 is still there.

thank you in advance.
[image: field1 dependent of field4]

Answer (score 1):

The field name cannot be hidden because it is not in any control.

You can add a **Section** control (under *HOME* > *Controls* on ribbon) to the form and then put the field name (text) and the field1 control within.

After that, apply the rules on the Section to hide it on condition.

[image]

[image]

Here is the outcome:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Madeline Would you accept it as answer if you confirm it to be helpful? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well. Thanks.

Comment: I would accept this as the answer to my question, but I don't know how to "accept" it. I thought by increasing the vote would do.

Comment: @Madeline Ok that's fine. Thanks anyway.